# How to make django-better-admin-arrayfield work with Wagtail CMS?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am working with wagtail cms and want to use ArrayField. The default form for it is very inconvenient. I found a [python package](https://github.com/gradam/django-better-admin-arrayfield) that has a better form field that is developed for Django admin. Also in the wagtail repository, I found an [issue](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/7182) where an author states that he was able to make [django-better-admin-arrayfield](https://github.com/gradam/django-better-admin-arrayfield) work with wagtail. I made several attempts but failed. Can anyone help me do it?

Update:

Model:

```py
class Reaction(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ReactionCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    randomized_sentences = ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True, null=True), null=True)
panels = [
        FieldPanel('category'),
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('icon'),
        FieldPanel('randomized_sentences', widget=DynamicArrayTextareaWidget)
    ]
```

ModelAdmin:

```py
class ReactionAdmin(ModelAdmin, DynamicArrayMixin):
    model = Reaction
    menu_label = 'Reactions'
    menu_icon = 'comment'
    list_display = ('name', 'category')
    search_fields = ('name', 'category__name')
```

I also added django_better_admin_arrayfield.css and django_better_admin_arrayfield.js to my static files directory. With all this done, The edit control for randomized_sentences looks like this: [image] It not only looks not as expected but also adds additional '`'s in unexpected places.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Could you please provide details about what you tried and how it failed?

Comment: Can please update this post with what you have tried so far? Please include anything you think is relevant, but at least I think we will need to see, installed apps, the ModelAdmin class which you want to use the django better array field for, simply to dispel any misconfiguration. Also, it would be great to see any errors that occurred before you added the workaround specified in your github issue.

Comment: Updated the question please take a look

Comment: @AntoinePinsard

Comment: @Swift Please take a look

Comment: How did you create the object in your screenshot exactly? Was that created in code somewhere that isnt posted in the question?

Comment: Please also post the javascript code you used to patch the issue to get you as far as you did (as this might have caused the odd behaviour youve presented in this question)

Comment: I use only the javascript code provided by the  django-better-admin-arrayfield lib